# Compiling FFMPEG for ARM

Tags: ffmpeg, compile, arm, beagleboard

I have a Linux ARM computer (BeagleBone Black).  I am trying to do some camera streaming and need FFMPEG to do it. I have tried everything that I can think of (including following guides for compiling it in general), but have failed to compile FFMPEG (for ARM) without fatal errors.

ubuntu@ubuntu-armhf:~/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg$ ./configure --prefix="$HOME/ffmpeg_build" \

> --extra-cflags="-I$HOME/ffmpeg_build/include" --extra-ldflags="-L$HOME/ffmpeg_build/lib" \
> --bindir="$HOME/bin" --extra-libs="-ldl" --enable-gpl --enable-libass --enable-libfdk-aac \
> --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx \
> --enable-libx264 --enable-nonfree --enable-x11grab
>
> ERROR: libfdk_aac not found

Does anyone know how to compile FFMPEG for an ARMv7 processor?

Comment: The general wisdom is that you compile it the same way you would for x86, except using a (cross) compiler toolchain for your architecture. What *exact* "fatal errors" are you getting? There may be a missing dependency, compiler version problem, or some other nuance. Just because you get a fatal error doesn't mean that your approach is fundamentally wrong. It just means we have to look closer at the problem.

Comment: Unfortunately, this type of question will almost definitely require a huge amount of back and forth discussion between us to resolve. You can continue to work on this with us here in comments, but be apprised, if you can gain 20 reputation, it would be much better to [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118/root-access) about this than to talk in comments.

Comment: Information required to begin helping you: Are you trying to compile ffmpeg on the Beagle **itself**, or on a standard desktop computer? In either case, which compiler are you using? The output of `gcc -v` would be useful. Also note any applicable information about which Linux distro you're using, the `./configure` command line you pass, and the exact compiler invocation and error message that you receive (make sure not to pass `-j` to `make` to avoid obscuring the error message!)

Comment: if you had sufficient resources, you could compile it on the beagleboard itself. More information would help, certainly.

Comment: To address 'allquixotic's comments, I hadn't originally posted the output from previous attempts because the output was overflowing the buffer, and I couldn't copy out all the output (easily). Would you like to see the uncut output? As for your second comment, I was thinking the same thing... but I don't usually use SE forums. How can I earn enough points (Other than answering questions), if there is a way? I barely have enough applicable knowledge to ask a question on these forums (SuperUser), let alone answer one.

Comment: I have been trying to do it on the beagle. Will that not work? I did it with node, and that worked fine. I am running Ubuntu, and was trying to follow this: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/UbuntuCompilationGuide. I also tried to use the 'make' command on my own, but that failed too. (As you can probably tell, I have a spotty knowledge of Linux. I should be able to follow basic commands, but anything much more complex will probably not work).

Comment: Hey, look, you have 21 rep! (from question upvotes). Try coming to chat!

Comment: As you may already know, you can always use pastebin, dropbox or a similar service to store long outputs, screen captures, etc. on the web. Then, you can just insert links to them in your posts.

Comment: @Joe Sorry.. Forgot to mention: Had a lengthy discussion on the chat about this with allquixotic and co., was able to figure it out ;). Forgot to close the question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After having a lengthy discussion with @JourneymanGreek and @allquixotic [on the chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/11534025#11534025), I was able to find an answer to my question. I basically just started leaving out encoders to compile until it worked!

In this case, since the error message was libfdk_aac not found, removing the part of the config file that said `--enable-libfdk-aac1` did the trick